# How to Decrypt this code

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I have inserted a data manually in the DB using this

```
 INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1,'admin',AES_ENCRYPT('text', UNHEX(SHA2('My
 secret passphrase',512))),'kdc');
```

How can I get the decrypted value using PHP? I've been finding solution but it seems like it won't work.

This is the query I use to decrypt.

```
SELECT username, AES_DECRYPT('text',
 UNHEX(SHA2(password,512))),category FROM table_name
```

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it work?

Comment: I updated my question..

Comment: it only return to null..

Comment: Instead of 'text' use the column name there while decrypting.

Answer (score 0):

AES_DECRYPT has following argument AES_DECRYPT(crypt_str, key_str);
So use it like following. I hope your column name is `password`

```
SELECT username, AES_DECRYPT(\`password\`, UNHEX(SHA2('My secret passphrase',512))),category FROM table_name
```